# Excel 2016, turning a number into Years and Months automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have done a lot of research on this and can't find anything, so I don't even know if it is possible. However, maybe someone on here knows how to do this or even another way to accomplish what I want.

I have an excel worksheet that is calculating the "Break Even Point" for upgrading lights in a room to more energy efficent lights. I am trying to get the result to display as X Years and X months to break even. My idea was make 1 cell for years and 1 cell for months. I would have the years cell formatted for numbers up to 2 decimal points. I would then make the decimal and following numbers invisible to avoid confusion and have the month cell take the numbers following the decimal and turn that into months.

What I mean by the "Break Even Point" is how long until the new more energy efficent lights will have saved you enough money to equal the cost of installing them. I don't know if any of this is possible, but I want to try. Thanks for all your help.

The following picture helps show what I mean. The numbers are just thrown in to make sure it works. The formula I have in the Break Even result box is:

=IF(D31,(G27-G26)/D31,0)

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what cell it is you are working in, and what the exact formula is you already have? We can then tell you what the resulting formula should be based on what you already have.

Comment: Ok, I will add that as an edit.

Comment: And the cells you work in are D33 and F33, correct? You would need to round the D33 one, and use REST for F33.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am not an expert in Excel, but I have learned quite a bit in the last couple weeks with my new job. :)

Comment: I've posted you an answer. I don't have Excel here, only at work, so I'm not entirely sure it works, but I think it does.

Comment: Why do you want to format the year as 2 decimal places and then hide them?  Why not just format what you need (no decimal places)?

Comment: Because I thought I needed the 2 decimal places to be able to calculate the months, but I found another way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out how to do it the way I was trying (thank you for the help though LPChip, it got me going in the right direction), however, I found another way to do what I wanted to do.

I made another sheet for just formulas as part of the workbook to make it easier on me. I had one cell "F9" that calculated the total time (from the first sheet) in years which was 3.98.

I then created another cell "F10" that calculated F9 * 12 to get the total number of months (48).  I then had another cell "G10" that used the value in F10 to calculate and enter the result as Years and Months. This is the formula it used:

=(INT(F10/12)&" YEARS "&ROUNDDOWN(F10-12*INT(F10/12)&" ",0)) &" MONTHS"

The Rounddown was to prevent the months from having decimal places and rounding up would lead to it saying things like 3 years and 12 months, so I rounded down to avoid that.

The last thing I did was just had the cell D33 on the first sheet copy what was in cell G10 on the formula page.

All of that leads to this beautiful result:

[IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF77R.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the following cells would contain the following formula's:

D33:

```
=IF(D31,ROUNDDOWN((G27-G26)/D31,0),0)
```

This basically makes sure the left side of the , is returned

F33:

```
=IF(D31,MOD((G27-G26),D31),0)
```

This basically makes sure the right part of the , is returned.